# Is there a way to make pyspark faster using asyncio?

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-asyncio

I'm making a code that turns voice into text, but many errors have appeared and the code is not fast enough, how can I improve these aspects?

Dataframe (report.csv):

```py
sparkDataFrame = (\["John", '25/5/2023', \<a href="\<a href="https://jolimont.native-infinity.com.br/api/queueRecords/2023/01/02/1/call-crmsimples-2196928.mp3" target="\_blank"\>Baixar\</a\>" target="\_blank"\>\</a\>, 00:00:35\])
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd 
import wget 
import os 
import findspark 
from sparknlp.base import * 
from pyspark.sql.types import BinaryType 
from sparknlp.annotator import * 
import whisper 
import aiohttp 
import asyncio 
import nest_asyncio 
import time 

findspark.init()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("database").master("local[*]").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


#Define the colunms of the database
cols = ['Agente', 'Data/Hora', 'Gravação', 'Atendimento']

#Loads the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
csv = pd.read_csv("report.csv", sep=';', usecols=cols)

#Converts the "Atendimento" column to Pandas Timestamp
csv['Atendimento'] = pd.to_datetime(csv['Atendimento'])csv = csv.loc[csv['Atendimento'] > '00:00:15']

#Creates a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

#Creates the DataFrame Spark from the DataFrame pandas
sparkDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(csv)

#Defines a function to download and read the audio file
def download_audio(url):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'HTML.parser')link = soup.a['href']

   # Download the audio file using wget
   file = wget.download(link, out="audio.tmp")

   # Renames the file to the correct extension
   os.rename(file, "audio.mp3")

   # Reads the audio file in bytes
   with open("audio.mp3", "rb") as audio:
      data = audio.read()

   # Removes the downloaded file
   os.remove("audio.mp3")

   return data

#Registers the function as a Spark User-Defined Function (UDF)
download_audio_udf = udf(download_audio, BinaryType())

#Applies the download_audio function to download the audio files
sparkDataFrame = sparkDataFrame.withColumn("Audios", download_audio_udf(sparkDataFrame['Gravação']))

#Displays the resulting DataFrame
sparkDataFrame.show()
time.sleep(15)

#Defines an asynchronous function to download and transcribe the audio file

async def process_audio(row): 
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: 
    async with session.get(row) as response:data = await response.read()
    with open("audio.mp3", "wb") as audio:
        audio.write(data)
        file = 'audio.mp3'

        # Convert audio to text using the template
        model = whisper.load_model("small")
        result = model.transcribe(file, language="Portuguese")
        transcription_text = result["text"]

        os.remove(file)

        return transcription_text

#Function to process the audios asynchronously
async def process_audios(audios):tasks = []
    for row in audios:
        task = asyncio.create_task(process_audio(row))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

#Gets the URLs of the audios from the dataframe
urls = sparkDataFrame.select("Audios").take(3)[0]

#Converts the list of URLs to a list of strings
audios = [str(url) for url in urls]

#Allows a new event loop to run in Jupyter Notebook
nest_asyncio.apply()

#Creates a new event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

#Performs asynchronous processing of the audios in the event loop
transcriptions = loop.run_until_complete(process_audios(audios))

#Displays the obtained transcripts
for transcription in transcriptions:
    print("Transcription:", transcription)

#Closes the event loop
loop.close()
```

I tried to convert this audio into text, it worked but I need a solution that is faster, is there any way to speed up this code or make the process faster?

Comment: You can probably skip the part where you convert a list of urls into a list of urls.

Comment: The concept of spark is already to do parallel processing. Using another module for asynchronous operation is most likely not the way to go. However, I do not see anywhere that you configure spark with executors, cores, ram per core, etc. Are you sure the default spark configuration is ok for your purpose ? How many records do you have per partition ? Moreover, you create the original dataset on your master node. That means it will have to be distributed towards slaves. Can't you just your csv from a distirbuted file system ?